# What were the casualties and ship damage on each side of the Battle of Plum Point Bend, Tennessee?

Tags: naval, american-civil-war

Specifically, how many were killed/wounded/missing on each side?

Answer (score 4):

The best details I find concerning the [Battle of Plum Point Bend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Plum_Point_Bend) can be found in the book [The Naval History of the Civil War](https://books.google.com/books?id=j9R2AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA166&dq=Battle%20of%20Plum%20Point%20Bend&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjppfKeqOHTAhXm5IMKHeogDdIQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=Battle%20of%20Plum%20Point%20Bend&f=false),By David Dixon Porter

[image]

The book, discusses the engagement, and details the casualties on pg 167

from a report by the confederate commander:

> Our casualties were two killed and one wounded 
>   Signed JE Montgomery
>   Senior Captain commanding River Defence Fleet

The following paragraph details the Union casualties:

> On the Federal side there were only wounded Commander Stembel
>   seriously Fourth Master Reynolds and two slightly This was a small
>   list of for such a desperate brush and would to indicate rather
>   indifferent gunnery practice on the part of the Federals who their
>   heavy ordnance ought to have the enemy from the face of the water his
>   vessels were of wood and lightly built

---

Discussion of the conditions of the ships damaged or lost seems to vary among sources, the main agreement being that the ironsides the [USS Mound City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Mound_City_(1861)) , and the [USS Cincinnati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Cincinnati_(1861)) both were rammed repeatedly and retreated to shallow water, and sunk:

> The Cincinnati after proceeding some distance up the river sunk near
>   the Tennessee side The Cairo assisted the Mound City to the first
>   island above the scene of action where she also sunk

The confederate ships took assorted damage:

> The boiler or steam pipe of one of the leading vessels of the enemy
>   was exploded by a shot from the flag ship 'Benton' Lieut Com Phelps and three of enemy's vessels including the one encountered by the Cincinnati were disabled and drifted down the river A fifty pound rifle shot from the Carondelet passed through the boilers of another the enemy's vessels rendering her helpless...

The confederate ships all were able to withdraw, however.